# Local DNS Server on Android

Tags: android, dns

I want to know what should be starting point in Android source code to implement local DNS caching in Android. I want to have something like `pdnsd` or `djbdns`. Probably port `djbdns` on Android and modify flow so that Android framework points to `djbdns` for resolution.

If someone can point me to a file in Android source code that accesses the local DNS settings to resolve the domain name.

Comment: You can create a rule for iptables and route all traffic to 53 port to your local machine. this can be a good start.